# Debugging django project in docker-compose in VS code

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I cannot tune debugging django project from docker-compose in VS code.

**Docker-compose**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  helpdesk_web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: helpdesk_web
    volumes:
      - ./static:/usr/src/app/static
      - media:/usr/src/app/media
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "5678:5678"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - helpdesk_db

  helpdesk_db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: helpdesk_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: something
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: something
      POSTGRES_USER: something

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: helpdesk_nginx
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - helpdesk_web
      - helpdesk_db
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./static:/usr/src/app/static
      - media:/usr/src/app/media

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  media:
```

**DockerFile**:

```
FROM python:3.10

# Задаем рабочую директорию(app) внутри контейнера
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Запрещаем Python писать файлы .pyc на диск
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# Запрещает Python буферизовать stdout и stderr
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Копируем файл из рабочей директории на диске в рабочую директорию(/usr/src/app) контейнера
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Копирует все файлы из рабочей директории на диске в рабочую директорию контейнера
COPY . .

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**launch.json**:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Django DEBUG",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "pathMappings": [
              {
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app"
              }
            ],
            "port": 5678,
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
          },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**manage.py**

```
import os
import sys
from django.conf import settings

def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'helpdesk.settings')
    
    if settings.DEBUG: 
        import debugpy
        debugpy.listen(('0.0.0.0', 5678))
        print('Attached!')
    
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Actually I followed https://testdriven.io/blog/django-debugging-vs-code/ this article in my another project and everything works. But with that docker-compose it doesn't work. Are there any idea why it doesn't work?

UPD 1:
**settings.py**:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
import environ

env = environ.Env()
env.read_env()
env.read_env(env.str('../../../../', '.tds.env'))
env.read_env(env.str('../', '.env'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env("DEBUG")
```

**.env**:

```
DEBUG=True
```

Comment: Are you sure, that your 'manage.py' is running in debug mode? (Check your settings.py)

Comment: @C1sc0 yes, I am sure. I made UPD and attached additional files

Comment: Your localRoot and remoteRoot paths are correct? The tutorial says it should append the `/app` és static i think in you case.